# How to use pendulum as a base datetime library with Django?

Tags: python, django, pendulum

I would like to use [pendulum](https://pendulum.eustace.io/docs/) as a base datetime library with Django. So, a `DateTimeField` should work with `pendulum` objects, not `datetime` objects.

I have followed an example on pendulum's docs page and created a special field:

```
import pendulum
from django.db.models import DateTimeField as BaseDateTimeField


class DateTimeField(BaseDateTimeField):

    def value_to_string(self, obj):
        val = self.value_from_object(obj)

        if isinstance(value, pendulum.DateTime):
            return value.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')

        return '' if val is None else val.isoformat()
```

...and used that in my `models.py`:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    done = models.BooleanField()
    due_date = BaseDateTimeField()

    def is_today(self):
        return self.due_date.in_timezone('utc').date() == pendulum.today('utc').date()
```

...however I'm getting an error:

```
'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'in_timezone'
```

...which obviously means that Django treats `due_date` still as a `datetime` object, not a `pendulum` object.

Is there a possibility of switching to using pendulum as a base datetime library with Django?

P.S.

I think something is wrong with that docs snippet, `value` appears out of the blue, but I don't think that this is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to use your custom field :) You have `due_date = BaseDateTimeField()` instead of `due_date = DateTimeField()`

Comment: @PierreV. Yeah, you're right. I've corrected the mistake, still getting the error.